# How To Properly Display Weight vs Destination Table Rates

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods, table-rates

First time using Magento. Still learning the ins and outs of this software. I am trying to setup table rates... but my CSV file that I keep uploading keeps yielding an error.

How would I write this in an CSV file, so Magento understands what I want?:

"Orders shipped to anywhere in the US weighing less than 5
pounds should charge $10 for shipping. Weighing more than 5 but less
than 10 pounds should charge $20 for shipping, and all other orders
should be charged $30 for shipping."

This is what I want to accomplish.

Here is what I have:
[image]

Comment: Hi Jason and welcome to MageOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

Just export a CSV and have a look on the plenty tutorials about table rates.

You have to insert the land in ISO-3 code, so

```
USA, *, *, 0, 10
USA, *, *, 5, 20
USA, *, *, 10, 30
```

Should it. Maybe I forgot something, only wrote it down, though.

Comment: I have just updated my comment with an image of what I have in my file. So... it looks similar to what you have... but do I need the commas? The parentheses around the asterisk (*) and the question mark? Do I need to add those to my file as well?

Comment: The () are, because I wasn't sure, whether we need 2 or 3, so just removed it. If you use Excel, you need to make sure to use ","! So, open it in an editor of you choice and make sure you have Comma Separated Values ;)