# Weight vs destination customization

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods

Currently I have weight vs destination added as shipping method which works but it only calculates the item weight and gives the shipping charges accordingly, I would like to show the shipping charges for the item after its packaging is done. How do I configure that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of entering the **weight of the product**,  you can enter the **weight of the product after packaging** in `item weight` attribute field in backend.

Comment: But if the customer adds more than one product that customer will be charged on the shipping cost of the individual product instead of a cumulative shipping cost. Also more than 800 products so yeah!

Comment: if you use weight vs destination, than you can set shipping price based on weight of subtotal , you can check here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/70747/how-to-properly-display-weight-vs-destination-table-rates